# How to update a property on an MVC view using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC view that has a property BirdSize for a Bird on it.

When the weight or height select lists of the bird changes this BirdSize property's value can potentially change.

What I'm wanting is for this update to happen without complete screen refresh so jquery I guess.

I don't particularly want to duplicate the BirdSize property code but just want to use it as is.

So the class:

```
public class Bird
{
   public int WeightId { get; set; }
   public Weight Weight { get; set; }
   public int HeightId { get; set; }
   public Height Height { get; set; }


public string BirdSize
{
   if(Height == "Tall" && Weight == "Heavy") {
      return "Big";
   }
   else {
      return "Small";
   }
}
}
```

Then I have a View:

```
@model Ahb.Insite.HerdRegistration.WebUI.ViewModels.BirdModel

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/Views/HerdRegistrationWizard/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<h3>Bird Weight/h3>
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Bird.WeightId, Model.BirdWeightSelectListItems, new { @id = "weightddl" })
</div>
<h3>Bird Height/h3>
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Bird.HeightId, Model.BirdHeightSelectListItems, new { @id = "heightddl" })
</div>
<h3> Bird Size</h3>
<div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Bird.BirdSize)
</div>
```

So the selects would look like:

```
<select id="weightddl">
   <option value="1">Light</option>
   <option value="2">Medium</option>
   <option value="3">Heavy</option>
</select>

<select id="heightddl">
   <option value="1">Short</option>
   <option value="2">Medium</option>
   <option value="3">Tall</option>
</select>
```

So I guess I would do something in these script codes:

```
$('#weightddl').change(function() {
   //Do something to update birdsize
});

$('#heightddl').change(function() {
   //Do something to update birdsize
});
```

I'm not sure the best way of going about it. Only way I can think of is to use the new values to be sent to a server method which will create a new bird and send back that bird's size. Anyone know of a better way to get this functionality working?

Maybe you could use a partial view?

Comment: +1 for making the question very clear

Answer (score 2):

If the logic is really simple as you shown above then there is no problem of duplicating the code in JavaScript as done by @Jonas. Sometimes we have to break the rules(DRY) to achieve something that gives a better experience to the user. If you don't duplicate the code then you are making an additional request to the server and the bird will fly away before knowing it's size :)

But still if you want to do then..

**Models**

```
public class BirdViewModel
  {
    public Bird Bird { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Heights { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Weights { get; set; }
  }

  public class Bird
  {
    public int WeightId { get; set; }
    public int HeightId { get; set; }
    public string Weight { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }

    public string BirdSize
    {
      get
      {
        if (HeightId == 3 && WeightId == 3)
        {
          return "Big";
        }
        else
        {
          return "Small";
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Controller**

```
public class BirdController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      var model = new BirdViewModel();

      model.Weights = new[]
         {
           new SelectListItem{ Text = "Light", Value = "1" },
           new SelectListItem{ Text = "Medium", Value = "2" },
           new SelectListItem{ Text = "Heavy", Value = "3" }
         };

      model.Heights = new[]
         {
           new SelectListItem{ Text = "Short", Value = "1" },
           new SelectListItem{ Text = "Medium", Value = "2" },
           new SelectListItem{ Text = "Tall", Value = "3" }
         };

      return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult DisplaySize(Bird bird)
    {
      return PartialView(bird);
    }
  }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model Birds.Models.BirdViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    var ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions 
    {
       UpdateTargetId = "birdSize",
       Url = "Bird/DisplaySize"
    };
}

<h2>Index</h2>


@using (Ajax.BeginForm(ajaxOptions))
{
  <h3>Bird Weight</h3>
  <div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Bird.WeightId, Model.Weights, new { @id = "weightddl" })
  </div>
  <h3>Bird Height</h3>
  <div>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Bird.HeightId, Model.Heights, new { @id = "heightddl" })
  </div>
  <h3> Bird Size</h3>
  <div id="birdSize">
      @Html.Partial("DisplaySize", Model.Bird ?? new Birds.Models.Bird())
  </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("select").change(function () {
    $("form").submit();
  });
</script>
```

**DisplaySize.cshtml**

```
@model Birds.Models.Bird

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BirdSize)
```

I've used `Ajax.BeginForm` so you have to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` library.

Comment: Hi @VJAI nice sample! can you please tell me _how can I update the frontend `CSS height` using AJAX call to load from web `API MVC server`?_. For e.g. my user is clicking on an imageThumbnail, and I want to load the picture and attach the image  CSS height and width from server

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method would be to duplicate the code in Javascript, but then you're not DRY.  Simplest DRY solution would be an Ajax call that sends the height and weight to the server and receives back the size string in JSON.  You can then update the birdsize div.

Bottom line is, without duplicating the BirdSize code in javascript the only way to access it is to make a call to the server.  It doesn't have to be a full page post-back, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the birdsize div an id

```
<div id="birdsize">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Bird.BirdSize)
</div>
```

Then you can grab it and change it's content like this

```
$('#weightddl, #heightddl').change(function() {
  //Do something to update birdsize
  if($('#weightddl').val() == "3" && $('#heightddl').val() == "3")
      $('#birdsize').text('Big');
  else
      $('#birdsize').text('Small');
```

});